# How to write this xhr request in axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

How do I write the following code with Axios calls instead of `XMLHttpRequest`?

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("POST", "/attachments", true);
/*open an ajax request.*/

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
  var progress = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
  attachment.setUploadProgress(progress);
};

xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 201) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var url = xhr.responseText;
      attachment.setAttributes({ url: url, href: url });
    }, 30)
  }
};

attachment.setUploadProgress(10);

setTimeout(function() {
  xhr.send(attachment.file);
}, 30)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breakdown of original XHR function calls:

1. `POST`-ing a file to `/attachments` endpoint
2. `async` parameter is set to `true`
3. Sets a `progress`-event handler
4. Sets a `load`-event handler that checks for `201` status code

Axios equivalents:

1. Axios provides the following APIs to `POST` data:

   - [`axios.post(url[, data, [config]])`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config)
   - [`axios({ url, method: 'POST' })`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig)
   - [`axios.request({ url, method: 'POST' })`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosrequestconfig)
2. Axios calls are `async` by default, so no need to set a flag.
3. The `config` argument of the Axios calls takes an [`onUploadProgress`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) callback method to track progress of a file upload.
4. The response of the Axios call (a `Promise`) inherently indicates a `load` event. The response also contains the HTTP status code in [`response.status`](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema).

Altogether, the code translation would be similar to this:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

let attachment = /*...*/

async function postAttachment(file) {
  const config = {
    onUploadProgress(progressEvent) {
      const progress = progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100
      attachment.setUploadProgress(progress)
    }
  }

  const response = await axios.post('/attachments', file, config)

  if (response.status === 201) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const url = response.data
      attachment.setAttributes({ url, href: url })
    }, 30)
  }
}

setTimeout(() => {
  postAttachment(attachment.file);
}, 30)
```

Comment: Hey, I get a 419 status code in this request.

Comment: 419 is an authentication timeout. That's unrelated to the question.

Comment: what do u mean by an authentication timeout ? tony

Comment: See [reference](http://getstatuscode.com/419)